# Не адаптируется пазл - капча js под касания на мобильном устройстве

Tags: javascript, frontend, captcha, touch-event, touch

Решил написать простенький скрипт пазлов для капчи.

**Столкнулся с проблемой**: не могу адаптировать движения мыши для тача на телефоне.
На компьютерной версии всё работает плавно, на телефоне - вообще почти не работает (детали пазла не перетаскиваются).

```js
var is_touch = navigator.maxTouchPoints && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
const PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY = 3;
const PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT = '#000099';
var ctx, canvas, img, pieces, mainWidth, mainHeight, pieceWidth, pieceHeight, currentPiece, currentDroppedPiece, mouse, touch;
var count = 0, maxCount = 0, gamesCount = 0;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
function init() {
    img = new Image();
    let img_gen = ['https://biarby.ru/test/test/captcha-new/img/1.jpg', 'https://biarby.ru/test/test/captcha-new/img/2.jpg', 'https://biarby.ru/test/test/captcha-new/img/3.jpg', 'https://biarby.ru/test/test/captcha-new/img/4.jpg', 'https://biarby.ru/test/test/captcha-new/img/5.jpg'];
    let i = getRandomInt(0, 5);
    img.src = img_gen[i];
    img.addEventListener('load',onImage,false);
}

function onImage (e) {
    pieceWidth = Math.floor (img.width / PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY)
    pieceHeight = Math.floor (img.height / PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY)
    mainWidth = pieceWidth * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;
    mainHeight = pieceHeight * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;
    setCanvas ();
    initPuzzle ();
}

function setCanvas(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = mainWidth;
    canvas.height = mainHeight;
    canvas.style.border = "1px solid green";
}

function initPuzzle(){
    pieces = [];
    mouse = {x:0,y:0};
    touch = {x:0,y:0};
    currentPiece = null;
    currentDroppedPiece = null;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, mainWidth, mainHeight, 0, 0, mainWidth, mainHeight);
    if (!gamesCount) createTitle("Нажми, чтобы пройти капчу");
    buildPieces();
}

function createTitle (msg) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.globalAlpha = .5;
    ctx.fillRect (100,mainHeight - 40,mainWidth - 200,40);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(msg,mainWidth / 2,mainHeight - 20);
}

function buildPieces(){
    var i, piece, xPos = 0, yPos = 0;
    for (i = 0;i < PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;i++) {
        piece = {}; piece.sx = xPos; piece.sy = yPos; pieces.push(piece);
        xPos += pieceWidth;
        if (xPos >= mainWidth) {
            xPos = 0; yPos += pieceHeight;
        }
    }
    document.onmousedown = shufflePuzzle;
    document.ontouchstart = shufflePuzzle;
}

function shufflePuzzle() {
    pieces = shuffleArray(pieces);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,mainWidth,mainHeight);
    var i, piece, xPos = 0, yPos = 0;
    for (i = 0;i < pieces.length;i++) {
        piece = pieces[i]; piece.xPos = xPos; piece.yPos = yPos;
        ctx.drawImage (img, piece.sx, piece.sy, pieceWidth, pieceHeight, xPos, yPos, pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
        ctx.strokeRect (xPos, yPos, pieceWidth,pieceHeight);
        xPos += pieceWidth;
        if (xPos >= mainWidth){
            xPos = 0; yPos += pieceHeight;
        }
    }
    document.onmousedown = onPuzzleClick;
    document.ontouchstart = onPuzzleClick;
}

function onPuzzleClick(e){
    if (is_touch) {
        if (e.layerX || e.layerX == 0){
            touch.x = e.layerX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            touch.y = e.layerY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }
        else if(e.offsetX || e.offsetX == 0) {
            touch.x = e.offsetX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            touch.y = e.offsetY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }
        currentPiece = checkPieceClicked();
        if (currentPiece != null) {
            ctx.clearRect (currentPiece.xPos,currentPiece.yPos,pieceWidth,pieceHeight);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.globalAlpha = .9;
            ctx.drawImage (img, currentPiece.sx, currentPiece.sy, pieceWidth, pieceHeight,
                touch.x - (pieceWidth / 2), touch.y - (pieceHeight / 2), pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
            ctx.restore();
            document.ontouchmove = updatePuzzle;
            document.ontouchend = pieceDropped;
        }
    } else {
        if (e.layerX || e.layerX == 0){
            mouse.x = e.layerX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            mouse.y = e.layerY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }
        else if(e.offsetX || e.offsetX == 0) {
            mouse.x = e.offsetX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            mouse.y = e.offsetY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }
        currentPiece = checkPieceClicked();
        if (currentPiece != null) {
            ctx.clearRect (currentPiece.xPos,currentPiece.yPos,pieceWidth,pieceHeight);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.globalAlpha = .9;
            ctx.drawImage (img, currentPiece.sx, currentPiece.sy, pieceWidth, pieceHeight,
                mouse.x - (pieceWidth / 2), mouse.y - (pieceHeight / 2), pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
            ctx.restore();
            document.onmousemove = updatePuzzle;
            document.onmouseup = pieceDropped;
        }
    }
}

function checkPieceClicked() {
    if (is_touch) {
        var i, piece;
        for (i = 0;i < pieces.length;i++) {
            piece = pieces[i];
            if (touch.x < piece.xPos || touch.x > (piece.xPos + pieceWidth) ||
                touch.y < piece.yPos || touch.y > (piece.yPos + pieceHeight)) {
            }
            else return piece;
        }
        return null;
    } else {
        var i, piece;
        for (i = 0;i < pieces.length;i++) {
            piece = pieces[i];
            if (mouse.x < piece.xPos || mouse.x > (piece.xPos + pieceWidth) ||
                mouse.y < piece.yPos || mouse.y > (piece.yPos + pieceHeight)) {
            }
            else return piece;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

function updatePuzzle (e) {
    if (is_touch) {
        currentDroppedPiece = null;
        if (e.layerX || e.layerX == 0) {
            touch.x = e.layerX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            touch.y = e.layerY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }
        else if(e.offsetX || e.offsetX == 0) {
            touch.x = e.offsetX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            touch.y = e.offsetY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }
        ctx.clearRect (0,0,mainWidth,mainHeight);
        var i, piece;
        for (i = 0;i < pieces.length;i++) {
            piece = pieces[i];
            if (piece == currentPiece) continue;
            ctx.drawImage (img, piece.sx, piece.sy, pieceWidth, pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
            ctx.strokeRect (piece.xPos, piece.yPos, pieceWidth,pieceHeight);
            if (currentDroppedPiece == null){
                if (touch.x < piece.xPos || touch.x > (piece.xPos + pieceWidth) ||
                    touch.y < piece.yPos || touch.y > (piece.yPos + pieceHeight)) {
                }
                else {
                    currentDroppedPiece = piece;
                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.globalAlpha = .33;
                    ctx.fillStyle = PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT;
                    ctx.fillRect(currentDroppedPiece.xPos,currentDroppedPiece.yPos,pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
                    ctx.restore();
                }
            }
        }
        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalAlpha = .66;
        ctx.drawImage(img, currentPiece.sx, currentPiece.sy, pieceWidth, pieceHeight,
            touch.x - (pieceWidth / 2), touch.y - (pieceHeight / 2), pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.strokeRect( touch.x - (pieceWidth / 2), touch.y - (pieceHeight / 2), pieceWidth,pieceHeight);
    } else {
        currentDroppedPiece = null;
        if (e.layerX || e.layerX == 0) {
            mouse.x = e.layerX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            mouse.y = e.layerY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }
        else if(e.offsetX || e.offsetX == 0) {
            mouse.x = e.offsetX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            mouse.y = e.offsetY - canvas.offsetTop;
        }
        ctx.clearRect (0,0,mainWidth,mainHeight);
        var i, piece;
        for (i = 0;i < pieces.length;i++) {
            piece = pieces[i];
            if (piece == currentPiece) continue;
            ctx.drawImage (img, piece.sx, piece.sy, pieceWidth, pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
            ctx.strokeRect (piece.xPos, piece.yPos, pieceWidth,pieceHeight);
            if (currentDroppedPiece == null){
                if (mouse.x < piece.xPos || mouse.x > (piece.xPos + pieceWidth) ||
                    mouse.y < piece.yPos || mouse.y > (piece.yPos + pieceHeight)) {
                }
                else {
                    currentDroppedPiece = piece;
                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.globalAlpha = .33;
                    ctx.fillStyle = PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT;
                    ctx.fillRect(currentDroppedPiece.xPos,currentDroppedPiece.yPos,pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
                    ctx.restore();
                }
            }
        }
        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalAlpha = .66;
        ctx.drawImage(img, currentPiece.sx, currentPiece.sy, pieceWidth, pieceHeight,
            mouse.x - (pieceWidth / 2), mouse.y - (pieceHeight / 2), pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.strokeRect( mouse.x - (pieceWidth / 2), mouse.y - (pieceHeight / 2), pieceWidth,pieceHeight);
    }
}

function pieceDropped (e) {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.ontouchmove = null;
    document.ontouchend = null;
    if (currentDroppedPiece != null) {
        var tmp = {xPos:currentPiece.xPos,yPos:currentPiece.yPos};
        currentPiece.xPos = currentDroppedPiece.xPos;
        currentPiece.yPos = currentDroppedPiece.yPos;
        currentDroppedPiece.xPos = tmp.xPos;
        currentDroppedPiece.yPos = tmp.yPos;
        count++;
    }
    resetPuzzleAndCheckWin();
}

function resetPuzzleAndCheckWin() {
    ctx.clearRect (0,0,mainWidth,mainHeight);
    var gameWin = true;
    var i, piece;
    for (i = 0;i < pieces.length;i++) {
        piece = pieces[i];
        ctx.drawImage(img, piece.sx, piece.sy, pieceWidth, pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
        ctx.strokeRect(piece.xPos, piece.yPos, pieceWidth,pieceHeight);
        if (piece.xPos != piece.sx || piece.yPos != piece.sy) {
            gameWin = false;
        }
    }
    if (gameWin) {
        setTimeout(gameOver,330);
    }
}

function gameOver(){
    document.onmousedown = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.ontouchstart = null;
    document.ontouchmove = null;
    document.ontouchend = null;
    gamesCount++;
    initPuzzle();
    if (maxCount == 0) maxCount = count;
    createTitle ('Вы прошли капчу!');
    if (count < maxCount) maxCount = count;
    count = 0;
}

function shuffleArray (o) {
    for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
 <title>Капча</title>
<body onload="init();">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="279" height="180" style="border: 1px solid green;"></canvas>
  <script>var i = 1;</script>
  <noscript>Нет js</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

В чём ошибка?
Заранее спасибо!